# Duplicate file differences when creating a patch with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an already existing SVN checked-in branch. 

Using *TortoiseSVN*:

1. I used **SVN Checkout** to get the branch onto my local computer.
2. I merged a few lines of code into existing projects
3. I create new subfolders for the newly written code.
4. I **TortoiseSVN->Add** all the files for my new directories and files.
5. Finally, I go to **TortoiseSVN->Create Patch** and save the file as *myChanges.patch*.

When I open the patch, nearly all my differences per source file are listed 3-4 times each.

How can I avoid having duplicate entries in my diff file when I create my patches via *TortoiseSVN*?

Answer (score 7):

This is old question, but one I couldn't find answers.

I was having the same problem and found out that the problem was how I was creating patches. Steps to reproduce:

- create new folder
- add one or more files in the folder
- create patch and select both folder and files in it to be included

However, if I create patch by only selecting folder, resulting patch file will contain all files in the folder. If I don't want to include all files, I select only individual files and skip the folder completely. Both ways result a patch file where files are included only once.

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. Why would I want the file multiple times in the patch file? Bug still exists in 1.10.2. My workaround is using svn on the command line like some kind of nerd.

Comment: This is the answer!

Answer (score 2):

After conversing with many of my peers, I realized that I wasn't the only one to encounter the issue. When I asked them how they got around it, they informed me that they hand-edit the diffs when it occurs for them.

So I wrote a simple GUI tool to do this for us, both the code and executable can be downloaded from *GitHub*:
https://github.com/Kakarot/TortoiseDiffCleaner/releases

You drag and drop your **.diff** or **.patch** files onto the UI and it generates a clean version of each file without the duplicate entries.

Comment: good tool. but it ends up deleting files with same names in different paths. any solution?